# Set datastore parent for an entity using php in app engine

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

does any one know how to set parent for datastore entity in php to make hierarchy? unfortunately google cloud still hasnt published any documentation for using datastore in php that make php useless and there are no other resources other than one blog post on web.

Comment: Are you using https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/ to access datastore in PHP? If so, it should be fairly straight forward.

Comment: yes i use google api and i can connect to datastore but i dont know where to learn for example setting parent for entity to create my data. there is no documentation for datastore usage in php. if you know any or know how to set parent let me know

Comment: Unfortunately there's no good documentation other than the source code itself: https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/source/browse/trunk/src/contrib/Google_DatastoreService.php To create an entity with parent, use Google_Key::setPath()

Answer (score 0):

I've just made available the first release of a Datastore library for PHP that makes this pretty straight forward.

https://github.com/tomwalder/php-gds

There are some code samples in the 'examples' folder, but it would look a bit like this (I'll skip the boilerplate)...

```
// Grab the parent Entity from Datastore
$obj_will_shakespeare = $obj_author_store->fetchOne();

// Create the child
$obj_book = new GDS\Entity();
$obj_book->title = 'Romeo and Juliet';
$obj_book->isbn = '1840224339';

// Set the parent 
$obj_book->setAncestry($obj_will_shakespeare);

// Write the child to Datastore
$obj_book_store->upsert($obj_book);
```

This syntax also supported multiple levels of nesting.